# Issue in writing xpath to refer to only text of li element

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

I have written below xpath to refer to only the text of 'li' element, but it refers to entire 'li' element as highlighted in the image. What should the xpath which can refer to text of 'li' element in my case?

```
//div[@class='parent']//ul[@class='list-none']//li[contains(text(),'7')]/text()
```

Comment: The text _`7`_ is a text within a text node decendent of the `<li>` and not an WebElement. What is your actual usecase?

Comment: Firstly I wanted to fetch text('7') of li element and similarly text of other li element. And for second case existence of any specific text inside li element